# protobuf-net surrogate for DateTimeOffset

Tags: protobuf-net, datetimeoffset

I would like to set up a surrogate for Nullable.  I looked at the various examples, and I think what I am doing is correct:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class DateTimeOffsetProxy
{
    [ProtoMember(1)] public DateTime? UtcTime;

    public static implicit operator DateTimeOffsetProxy(DateTimeOffset? value)
    {
        return new DateTimeOffsetProxy() {UtcTime = value?.UtcDateTime};
    }

    public static implicit operator DateTime?(DateTimeOffsetProxy value)
    {
        return value.UtcTime;
    }
}
```

I am then doing this is a static constructor:

```
Model = RuntimeTypeModel.Default;
Model.AllowParseableTypes = true;           
Model.Add(typeof(DateTimeOffset?),false)
.SetSurrogate(typeof(DateTimeOffsetProxy));
```

At the call to Add, I am getting this exception:

System.ArgumentException : Data of this type has inbuilt behaviour, and cannot be added to a model in this way: System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTimeOffset, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]

I'm not sure why it is saying there is inbuilt behavior since the reason I was trying this was to resolve this exception serializing a class with a DateTimeOffset:

----> System.InvalidOperationException : No serializer defined for type: System.DateTimeOffset

We use DateTimeOffset and Nullable many places in our code, so I would like to come up with some way to handle this generically.

Can someone point out my error?

Comment: I removed the 'Model.AllowParseableTypes = true; ' line and it worked.  I guess that the inbuilt behavior it was overriding is the ToString/Parse combo that AllowParseableTypes enables.